# Scraping data with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm working on a program to scrape address data from companies from a website. For this, I already have built a list with the links where this data can be found. On each of those links, the page source of the data I need looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ddBF.jpg

For some reason though, I cannot seem to fetch the first line of the address, in this case "'t walletje 104 101"

All the other information comes through fine, as you can see here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5Fk6.jpg

This is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import string
import urllib

urllist=[]
url1="http://www.bisy.be/"

fname = "test2.txt"
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith(" <tr class="):
        words= line.split()
        url2 = words[6]
        url3 = url1 + url2[1:48]
        urllist.append(url3)


for link in urllist:
    document = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
    html = document.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    name = soup.find("br")
    name2 = name.text.strip()
    print (name2)
```

This code is doing the basics so far. Once everything works I will clean it and finetune it a bit. Is there anyone who can help me?
An example link for the people who want to check out the page source: http://www.bisy.be/?q=nl/bedrijf_fiche&id=KNO01C2015&nr=2027420160

Is there anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a workaround by finding `p` tag with specific font size:

```
elements = soup.find_all("p")
for tag in elements:
    try:
        if "9pt" in tag["style"]:
            details = tag.text
            print(details)
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

your can't select text in `br` it new line not like `p`, `span` `div` or others. you can try using BeautifulSoup above or use regex below which is faster

```
import re

for link in urllist:
  document = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
  html = document.read().decode('utf-8')
  name = re.compile(r"9pt; font-family: Arial;'>(.*?)<a",  re.DOTALL).findall(html)
  # clean html tag
  name = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', name[0])
  print(name)
```